# ReactiveUI: Using CanExecute with a ReactiveCommand

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, system.reactive, reactiveui

I'm starting to work with the ReactiveUI framework on a Silverlight project and need some help working with ReactiveCommands.

In my view model, I have something that looks roughly like this (this is just a simplified example):

```
public class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
  private int MaxRecords = 5;

  public ReactiveCommand AddNewRecord { get; protected set; }

  private ObservableCollection<string> _myCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
  public ObservableCollection<string> MyCollection
  {
    get
    {
      return _myCollection;
    }

    set
    {
      _myCollection = value;
      raiseCollectionChanged("MyCollection");
    }
  }

  MyViewModel()
  {
    var canAddRecords = Observable.Return<bool>(MyCollection.Count < MaxRecords);
    AddNewRecord = new ReactiveCommand(canAddRecords);

    AddNewRecord.Subscribe(x => 
    {
       MyCollection.Add("foo");
    }
  }
}
```

The `canAddRecords` function is getting evaluated the first time the `ReactiveCommand` is created, but it's not getting re-evaluated when items are added to `MyCollection`. Can anyone show me a good example of how to bind the `canExecute` property of a `ReactiveCommand` so that it gets automatically re-evaluated in this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, there's a better way to do this, change your ObservableCollection to ReactiveCollection (which inherits from ObservableCollection but adds some extra properties):

```
MyCollection = new ReactiveCollection<string>();

AddNewRecord = new ReactiveCommand(
    MyCollection.CollectionCountChanged.Select(count => count < MaxRecords));
```

The catch here now is though, you can't *overwrite* the MyCollection, only repopulate it (i.e. Clear() + Add()). Let me know if that's a dealbreaker, there's a way to get around that too though it's a bit more work.

Comment: My only other requirement is that I need the records in the Observable collection to be constantly sorted by 3 different fields. So when a new record is added, the collection automatically re-sorts. I'm not sure that's an entirely different question though.

Comment: And could you please explain why this approach is better? I'm not criticizing, I'm just new to Reactive and any additional info would be helpful.

Comment: So, when you use .Create, it's like RelayCommand - CanExecute has to be polled by Silverlight. Using the normal constructor means that as *soon* as the collection count changes, the CanExecute gets properly updated (via CanExecuteChanged) and the button greys/ungreys instantly.

Comment: If you're doing sorting, it's better to do that via the Collection View stuff - if that isn't possible, you can do it via an Output property, but you'll have to rebuild the collection each change.

Comment: It looks like when you create the `ReactiveCommand` using the method you suggested the `canExecute` check doesn't happen until after `MyCollection` is changed. So it doesn't work for situations where I only want the command to be executable when `MyCollection.Count > 0` initially. Once the `MyCollection` changes, it works as intended. Any suggestions for this situation?

Comment: StartWith(0) should do it, sorry about that

Comment: Using `AddNewRecord = new ReactiveCommand(
    MyCollection.CollectionCountChanged.Select(count => count > 0)).StartWith(false);` worked for that last situation. Thanks for the help Paul and thanks for all the obvious hard work you put into ReactiveUI. :)

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured this one out. Using `ReactiveCommand.Create()` worked for my situation.

```
MyViewModel()
{
  AddNewRecord = ReactiveCommand.Create(x => MyCollection.Count < MaxRecords);

  AddNewRecord.Subscribe(x => 
  {
     MyCollection.Add("foo");
  }
}
```