# ReactiveUI: CanExecute with a non collection property

Tags: reactiveui, reactivevalidatedobject

I've seen question [ReactiveUI: Using CanExecute with a ReactiveCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754928/reactiveui-using-canexecute-with-a-reactivecommand), however my issue is that I have a string property, UniqueID, and I want it to only execute when it has a length equal to 7. I cannot seem to come up with an observer that doesn't crash the program. What is the correct simple way to do this?

```
public class MainViewModel : ReactiveValidatedObject
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        RetrieveRecord = new ReactiveAsyncCommand(/* what goes here for CanExecute */);
        RetrieveRecord.Subscriber(x => Record = new Record(UniqueId));

        // or do we use the method RetrieveRecord.CanExecute()?
        // the next line crashes the app

        RetrieveRecord.CanExecute(UniqueId.Length == 7);
    }

    public ReactiveAsyncCommand RetrieveRecord { get; private set; }

    string _uniqueId;
    public string UniqueId
    {
        get { return _uniqueId; }
        set
        {
            _clientId = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(x => x.UniqueId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
RetrieveRecord = new ReactiveAsyncCommand(
    this.WhenAny(x => x.UniqueId, x => x.Value.Length == 7));
```

Comment: it doesn't work. There is no "Length" property on 2nd param and does not compile. I did try the following causing the app to fail: new ReactiveAsyncCommand(this.WhenAny(x => x.UniqueId, x => x.Value.Length == 7));

Comment: The 3rd inner exception says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: The object that is null is the MainViewModel and the reason why it is null as because of the error being thrown by the ctor's new ReactiveAsyncCommand. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: The 2 errors before that are "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Comment: tried to paste stack trace, but it is enormous. Here are some pieces. [1st part] ReactiveUI.WhenAnyMixin.<>c__DisplayClassd`3.<WhenAny>b__a(IObserver`1 subject) in c:\\Users\\Administrator\\Dropbox\\ReactiveUI_External\\ReactiveUI\\VariadicTemplates.cs:line 40 [2nd part] ReactiveUI.Xaml.ReactiveAsyncCommand.commonCtor() in c:\\..\\ReactiveUI_External\\ReactiveUI.Xaml\\ReactiveAsyncCommand.cs:line 114   at ReactiveUI.Xaml.ReactiveAsyncCommand..ctor() in c:\\..\\ReactiveUI_External\\ReactiveUI.Xaml\\ReactiveAsyncCommand.cs:line 37

Comment: Enable 1st chance exceptions, you'll get a better stack. Also, http://gist.github.com

Comment: FYI: I installed ReactiveUI via Nuget (System.Reactive.Windows.Threading = 1.1.11011.0). The first chance exception is as follows: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reactive.Windows.Threading, Version=1.1.10621.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).

Comment: Ah! This is a known bug I need to fix, add "RxApp.DeferredScheduler = DispatcherScheduler.Instance" to your App.Xaml.cs constructor

Comment: The same first chance exception happens, except this time it happens on "RxApp.DeferredScheduler = DispatcherScheduler.Instance" in the App.Xaml.cs constructor.

Comment: That's fine, ignore it for now

Comment: app still doesn't run. throws exception as i initially pointed out in the comments... Nuget Packages: id="reactiveui-core" version="2.5.0.0", id="reactiveui-xaml" version="2.5.0.0", id="Rx_Experimental-Main" version="1.1.11011", id="Rx_Experimental-Xaml" version="1.1.11011"

Comment: Send an Email to the mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/reactivexaml?pli=1